# Anonymous ActionListener Class Exception "NullPointerException"

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, actionlistener, anonymous-class

In a for loop, I want to

- initialize JButtons [] *bts*  .
- add the buttons  to a panel *pan3* .
- add an **ActionListener** to each JButton .

here what I've got so far :

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < bts1.length ; i++){
        bts1[i] = new JButton(""+i);
        pan3.add(bts1[i]);
        //The NullPointerException happens after this line . 
        bts[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                int j = 0 ;
                screen.setText(screen.getText()+bts[j].getText());
                j++;
            }
        });
    }
```

**My question** is how to solve the NullPointerException ?
*note*
for the  j I add it because when I tried to use the  i , a compiler error occurs ,

Comment: j will always be zero for the setText stuff.  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: no it will increment by 1 as j++ written

Comment: Then it will immediately fall out of scope and be forgotten.  And, the next time in it gets reset to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized `JButton` as `bts1` and calling it as `bts`. I think that caused the error.
Also,

Declare `int i=0;` as **global scope** and `for(i = 0 ;i < bts1.length ; i++)` then you can use `i` instead of `j`.
Or else use as following:

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < bts1.length ; i++){
        bts1[i] = new JButton(""+i);
        pan3.add(bts1[i]);
        final int j=i; 
        bts1[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){                   
                screen.setText(screen.getText()+bts1[j].getText());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: using the `final` modifier so he can use `i` is a good point :)

Comment: Thanks . It works now , would you clarify why did you use the final modifier here ?

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables-java

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different arrays of JButtons, `bts` and `bts1`.

- In your loop you are creating a JButton and assign it to `bts1[i]`.
- In the ActionListener part you are accessing `bts[j]`.

Have you initialized also `bts[j]` somewhere? If not you will run into a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Try the event source instead

```
screen.setText(screen.getText()+((JButton)ae.getSource()).getText());
```

Comment: I would understand it better if you add more explanation of what is the differences between these two

Comment: You can use the event source - the clicked button instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:
for(int i = 0 ;i < bts1.length-1 ; i++){
   //rest of your code
}
```

As the array of 10 elements has elements with indexes 0 through 9, not 0 through 10.

Answer (score 0):

Beforr you add the button to Panels. You need add Listener for button first.

Have a try with the following code first.

```
    //The NullPointerException happens after this line . 
    bts[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            int j = 0 ;
            screen.setText(screen.getText()+bts[j].getText());
            j++;
        }
    });

    **pan3.add(bts1[i]);**
```