# Pass function argument to callback function in Java

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public void FbShare(JSONObject parameters) {

    if (Session.getActiveSession() == null || !Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {

        Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                if (state.isOpened()) {
                    publishFeedDialog(parameters);  // <--- HERE
                }
            }
        };

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    } else {
        publishFeedDialog(parameters);
    }
}
```

Why is `parameters` not accessible in the `publishFeedDialog(parameters)`call?

Comment: make it final -> `public void FbShare(final JSONObject parameters)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `parameters` parameter as `final`:

```
public void FbShare(final JSONObject parameters) {
 //...    
}
```

For an overview of what's happening, see:

- [Why Java inner classes require "final" outer instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables-java)
- [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Answer (score 4):

Trying making that argument final:

```
public void FbShare(final JSONObject parameters) {
```

Comment: `final` in java is the same as `const` in C++? Does it mean that I cannot change the values of `parameters` argument?

Comment: No, not the same.  final says the reference won't change.  Java is pass by value, and for objects the value is a reference type.  You can't change the reference, but you can change the mutable state of the object the reference points to if it allows you to. const in C++ is a much wider ranging keyword.

Comment: You mean the reference cannot point to other object, or the object it is pointing will not be changes inside the function.

Comment: I think I was clear: the reference itself cannot change.

Answer (score 2):

Change the first line to

```
public void FbShare(final JSONObject parameters) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error message tells you everything you need to know, if you can decipher it:

```
 Cannot refer to the non-final local variable parameters in an enclosing scope
```

That is, the variable `parameters` in the enclosing scope is not `final`, so it can't be referred to.

To fix that, make it `final`:

```
 public void FbShare(final JSONObject parameters) {
```

Java isn't clever enough to keep track of what `parameters` refers to, unless you use `final` to guarantee that it's always going to point at the same object.

This would equally apply if you were referring to a local variable that wasn't a method parameter:

```
 public void foo() {
      final String bar = ...;
      Callback callback = new Callback() {
           void invoke() { 
               something(bar); 
           }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your parameters as final so it can be used within your anonymous class.