# Does anonymous class get shallow or deep copy of final variables in Java?

Tags: java, deep-copy, anonymous-class, shallow-copy

I"ve read [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-java-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables)

and see that a anonymous class gets copies of the execution context of the outer class variables. No where can i find if the anonymous class gets a shallow copy or deep copy of the final variables. I tried doing a test using 
Using some android code but it can be any java platform. I tried to test this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    final List<String> jason = new ArrayList<>();
    jason.add("my first string");
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("mytag",jason.get(0));
        }
    });
    jason.clear();
    jason.add("my second string");

}
```

}

and the output in the logs when i click the text is `"my second string".`

so it seems that when i alter the list from the outer class it indeed affected the anonymous class. So can i assume it always gets a shallow copy then ?

Comment: It gets a copy of the *variables*, not the objects that the (reference) variables refer to.

Comment: im not clear, could someone post a example possibly using my example.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the distinction between variables and objects?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - Referring to *local* variables here, not member variables.  Whilst semantically it doesn't get a copy, this is probably how the implementation works (and is the language used by the post the OP refers to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class):

> ... a local class has access to local variables.

(where "local class" also applies to "anonymous class").

Note that it says *variables*, not *objects*.  So there is no deep copying going on.

---

You can verify this experimentally with the following code:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(5);

new Runnable() { public void run() { list.add(6); } }.run();

System.out.println(list);   // [5, 6] (would be [5] if had been deep-copied)
```

([Live demo](http://ideone.com/v89b7K))