# Safe publication of local final references

Tags: java, multithreading, safe-publication

I know that you can safely publish a non-thread safe object by writing the reference to a `final` or `volatile` field which will later be read by exactly one other thread, provided that upon publication, the thread that created the object discards the reference to it so it can no longer interfere with or unsafely observe the object's use in the other thread.

But in this example, there's no explicit `final` field, only `final` local variables.  **If the caller discards its reference to `unsafe`, is this safe publication?**

```
void publish(final Unsafe unsafe) {
    mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do something with unsafe
        }
    }
}
```

I found a few Q&As, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-java-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables), suggesting that `final` local variables are implicitly "copied" into anonymous classes.  Does that mean that the above example is equivalent to this?

```
void publish(final Unsafe unsafe) {
    mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        final Unsafe mUnsafe = unsafe;
        public void run() {
            // do something with mUnsafe
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit for clarification:**

`Unsafe` could be anything, but say it's something like this:

```
public class Unsafe {
    public int x;
}
```

And `mExecutor` is anything that satisfies the contract of `Executor`.

Comment: Your executor is using a thread safe queue. To see this issue you have to pass the object between threads without using appropriate memory barriers anywhere.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  `class Executor { void execute(Runnable r) { } }` - no queue here. But the point is *probably* valid nevertheless...

Comment: BTW `Unsafe` is a class which has a singleton, though you can create more of them...

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not referring to `sun.misc.Unsafe`.  Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Although, admittedly, I'm not entirely sure that I got the actual point of your question, and (as pointed out in the comments) the issue is likely not really an issue in your particular case, maybe the relevant insights can be gained from a test/example</sub>

Considering the following class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

class Unsafe
{

}

class SafePublication
{
    private final ExecutorService mExecutor = null;

    public void publish(final Unsafe unsafe)
    {
        mExecutor.execute(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // do something with unsafe
                System.out.println(unsafe);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

One can compile it, and obtain two `.class` files:

- `SafePublication.class`
- `SafePublication$1.class` for the inner class

Decompiling the class file for the inner class yields the following:

```
class SafePublication$1 implements java.lang.Runnable {
  final Unsafe val$unsafe;

  final SafePublication this$0;

  SafePublication$1(SafePublication, Unsafe);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LSafePublication;
       5: aload_0
       6: aload_2
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field val$unsafe:LUnsafe;
      10: aload_0
      11: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      14: return

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: aload_0
       4: getfield      #2                  // Field val$unsafe:LUnsafe;
       7: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      10: return
}
```

One can see that for the `final` parameter, there is indeed a field introduced in this class. This field is `val$unsafe`, and it is a [final field in the class file sense](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5-200-A.1), and it is initialized in the constructor.

(This is not entirely equivalent to the second code snippet that you posted, because the second one contains *two* final fields, and they are both initialized with the same value. But regarding the issue of safe publication, the effect should be the same).

Comment: This is exactly what I was getting at.

Answer (score 3):

You left some important code out of your first example:  The `mExecutor` object probably owns a `BlockingQueue`.  The `mExecutor.execute(r)` call probably calls `q.put(r)` to add your task to the queue, and then sometime later, the worker thread calls `r=q.take()` to obtain the task before it can call `r.run()`.

The `put()` and `take()` methods of the blocking queue will establish the same kind of "happens before" relationship between events in the two threads that would be established by one of the "safe publication" idioms.

Whatever the first thread updates in memory before calling `q.put(r)` is guaranteed to become visible to the second before the `q.take()` call returns.

Comment: The argument you make I think misses the point here: the OP is explicitly talking about non thread-safe objects, the „happens before“ semantics helps set the reference but not against mutating a mutable object by the caller *after* the Runnable has been put into the queue and possible exactly at the same time as it is being used in the Runnable. So in fact it guarantees exactly nothing in terms of thread safety and safe publication in regards to accessing the local variable in question.

Comment: @TomaszStanczak, OP seemed to say that would not happen, "...provided that upon publication, the thread that created the object discards the reference to it so it can no longer interfere with or unsafely observe the object's use in the other thread."

Comment: And exactly this is the guarantee and not the "happens before" relationship of `put` and `get`, that per itself cannot give this guarantee. Actually already the function call has this relationship, what happens is: 1. call publish, 2. put, 3. get. If the original variable reference gets discarded the call of `publish` is enough regardless of what happens next.

Comment: @jameslarge The key is passing the reference in some manner that creates a memory barrier, so that values previously written to unsynchronized fields in the publishing thread are guaranteed to be visible to the receiving thread.  Discarding the reference has nothing to do with that, per se; it just avoids subsequent unsafe use in the publishing thread.  I think you're correct that a `BlockingQueue` would provide this guarantee, and any practical `Executor` probably does have a `BlockingQueue` or something like it, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @jameslarge it was me that obviously had missed the point :-) - discarding the reference is not questioned and memory barrier was asked about and not the other way round...

Comment: I am still not quite happy with `BlockingQueue`, it seems to not use `synchronized` keyword so cannot be a sufficient memory barrier for the `Unsafe`'s  unsynchronized fields.

Comment: The `BlockingQueue` is perfectly safe. Using `synchronized` isn't the end all be all for thread safety. The `LinkedBlockingQueue` uses a `Lock` which is equivalent to `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be partly answered by this answer:

[Java multi-threading & Safe Publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication)

at least regarding "safe publication".

Now if the caller discards its reference the variable will be safe, because there exist no reference to the variable except in the final local variable.

And regarding the code examples - in my eyes both code snippets are equivalent. Introducing an additional local variable doesn't change the semantics, in both cases the compiler recognizes the reference as immutable and let you go with it.

**EDIT - I am leaving this part to document my misinterpretation of the OP's question**

To clarify - I take usage of `final` or  `volatile` as granted in this example, so the proper memory barrier catering for the visibility of the object reference is there, the only point is the possible mutability of the non thread-safe object which cannot be guaranteed using memory barriers and actually has nothing to do with them. It can be taken care of either through proper synchronization or leaving only one reference to the content.

**EDIT2 – after reading the OP’s comments**

I have just looked at the [JSR 133 FAQ](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) - AFAIU a safe publication of a reference to object using a memory barrier doesn't guarantee that the unsychronized fields of the mentioned referenced object are visible too. Neither by `final` nor `volatile`.

If I am not misinterpreting this FAQ only synchronizing on the same monitor defines a “happens-before” relationship for **all** the writes one thread did before releasing the synchronizing lock and acquiring the lock on the same monitor by another thread.

I may be mistaken but it sounds to me as if also non-synchronized fields of the referenced object would be visible.

If using `final` keyword (like in your example where the parameter gets inserted as a `final` field) - only instance fields of the referenced object that themselves are `final` are guaranteed to be visible after the construction of the object ends.

But in the `BlockingQueue` (and as its implementation the `LinkedBlockingQueue`) I see no `synchronized` keyword whatsoever – it seems that it uses some very clever code to implement synchronization by using `volatile` fields, to me it doesn’t sound like a synchronization on a monitor in the sense described in JSR 133.

Which would mean that common blocking queues used by Executor do not guarantee visibility of non-final fields of your `Unsafe` instances. While the reference itself can be safely published using just the `final` keyword, the safe publishing of the fields this reference points to requires either the fields to be `final`, too, or a synchronization with a monitor shared by the writer and reader.

Don’t shoot the messenger :-).