# "Variable is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final" error in custom adapter

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

I'm attempting to implement a multiple choice ListView with checkboxes, and I've defined a custom adapter class, and it's as follows:

```
package com.ameer.easycooking;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<String> categoryList;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();

    public CategoryAdapter(List<String> categoryList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.category_list_item, categoryList);
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class CategoryHolder {
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private TextView categoryName;

        public CategoryHolder(CheckBox checkBox, TextView categoryName) {
            this.checkBox = checkBox;
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }

        public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
            return checkBox;
        }

        public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
            this.checkBox = checkBox;
        }

        public TextView getCategoryName() {
            return categoryName;
        }

        public void setCategoryName(TextView categoryName) {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        CategoryHolder holder = new CategoryHolder((CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox), (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, null);

            holder.getCheckBox().setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            selected.add(holder.getCheckBox().getText().toString());
                        }else{
                            selected.remove(holder.getCheckBox().getText().toString());
                        }
                }
            });
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CategoryHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        String category = categoryList.get(position);
        holder.categoryName.setText(category);
        holder.checkBox.setTag(category);

        return v;
    }

    public List<String> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

I would like to store checked items in the `selected` List and then retrieve them with the getter at the end of the class, but It's telling me that 'holder' needs to be declared final, and if I do declare it final I can no longer assign a value to it using `holder = (CategoryHolder) v.getTag();` So solving one problem is creating another one. :( How can I solve both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your holder is an inner class. You need to declare it as a global variable, then initialize it when you require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the necessary information from the parameters of the `OnCheckedChangeListener`: `buttonView` is the checked element. So all you need to do is the following:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       CheckBox checkbox;
       if (buttonView instanceof CheckBox )
       {
           checkbox = (CheckBox)buttonView;
       }
       else return;

       if (isChecked) {
            selected.add(checkbox.getText().toString());
       }else{
            selected.remove(checkbox.getText().toString());
       }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to be as you suggested, but now I'm getting a null pointer exception at `CategoryHolder holder = new CategoryHolder((CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox), (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name));` Why's that?

Comment: @user3501779 - Glad to hear my answer got you one step further: at least now it's running... somehow ;-) You're getting a NPE because `convertView` may be `null` sometimes. So if you assign `null` to `v`, then `v.findViewById()` causes a NPE.

Comment: Following this info, I move the above line into the `if (convertView == null)` condition, and it's working now and displaying the items in the ListView. However, I'm always getting an empty string in `selected`. Does the `getText()` method return CheckBox text or TextView text? I'm thinking that's where the problem could be, since I'm not assigning anything to CheckBox text, but rather to the corresponding TextView.

Comment: Solved it. I should have used `setText()` on the CheckBoxes rather than `setTag()`, so now I can also omit the TextViews from the adapter entirely. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3501779 - You're welcome :) Just keep in mind you also could retrieve the category from the CheckBox (even without casting) by using `View.getTag().toString()` Tags can be quite handy sometimes

Answer (score 0):

If you use object to inner class you should declare it `final`.
It is explained here: [Why Java inner classes require "final" outer instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-java-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables)

So, you can make that variable final:

```
final CategoryHolder holder = convertView != null ? 
    (CategoryHolder) v.getTag() :
    new CategoryHolder((CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox), (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name));
```