# Why referring Outer Class non-final variables inside method of a inner Class No longer gives an error

Tags: java, class, final

I found that we can not use a non-final variable inside the method of an inner Class, But when I did an experiment myself I got the different result

There are few Answers on StackOverflow describing the reason [Why Java inner classes require "final" outer instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-java-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables) , I understood the concept, And tried it myself with two classes in IntelliJ

`Driver` Class

```
public class Driver{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String outsideVar = "anything";
  InterfaceClassTest object1 = new InterfaceClassTest() {
        @Override
        public void InterfaceFunction() {
                System.out.println(outsideVar);
         }
    };
  object1.InterfaceFunction();  
};}
```

`InterfaceClassTest` Class

```
 public interface InterfaceClassTest {
  public abstract void InterfaceFunction();
  }
```

I expected I would get an error for the above code, But it worked fine, So how come I can use `outsideVar` in inner class's method

Comment: The variable is effectively final, IE the compiler can detect that no changes are made to it.  This changed in java 8(? might have been earlier)

Comment: @DavidZimmerman oh, Yes that must be the reason, I have updated version of JAVA, Thanks!