# Convert class method to thread support

Tags: java, multithreading

Getting this error when calling another method and passing string parameter inside the thready run method....ERROR IS "Change modifier of titlePartnerF to final"..
method which I am trying to call using for send push notifications which should be run in background.

```
String titlePartnerF= titlePartner; 
final MerchantBeanPush pushBeanF = pushBean ;
// MULTHREADING CODE 
// KAMLESH DAVE : 03-FEB-2019
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* * Do something inside the thread*/
        PushNotifictionHelper.sendPushNotification("W",pushBeanF.getWebToken(),titlePartnerF,messageP, bodyPartner);    
    }
});
t.start();
System.out.println("we are outside from method now in background+++++++++++");
```

[image]

Comment: `final String titlePartnerF = titlePartner;`?

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: *"Change modifier of titlePartnerF to final"* What is exactly you don't understand about this message?

Comment: when i am passing normal string variable to inside run method then eclipse showing me this warning message "Change modifier of titlePartnerF to final" where titlePartnerF is a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable referred to within an inner class must be declared final or be effectively final.

`String titlePartnerF= titlePartner;` needs to be `final String titlePartnerF= titlePartner;`

Have a look at explanation here: [Why Java inner classes require "final" outer instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910324/why-java-inner-classes-require-final-outer-instance-variables)